# Playing video using Flash as a Fallback to Video.js

Tags: flash, video

Videos with FF, Chrome are running well. So, for Ie7 and Ie8 i am having problem. 
With flash fallback,

Your browser does not support video...</p>
           </object>
]]>

I can't play video. If i replace url param with something that is already hosted, video works. Why is it not playing video from my local?

Answer (score 0):

sounds like an activeX issue, especially if you're on IE, also make sure your link is correct, i believe there are multiple places where you need to change it

```
<param name="movie" value="your.swf" /> and

<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="your.swf" width="533" height="337">
```

Comment: <object class="aligncenter" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" width="560" height="315">
      <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf"/>
      <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/>
      <param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
      <param name="flashvars" value="config={'clip': {'url':'Video/GetFile?guid=301a0e215cc24ade9960e307c2c7a8cc&filename=oceans-clip.mp4','type'=video/mp4,'autoPlay':false, 'autoBuffering':true }}"/>
    
        </object>

Comment: I have something like this.. but it doesnt work. Flash doesn't seem to understand the url param.

Comment: try making the url absolute.